# How do I create an SEO-friendly link for custom, dynamically generated pages in Opencart?

Tags: php, seo, opencart, url-routing

I'm using Opencart 2.0 framework

I have controller that is called happy_hours.php
there I'm looping through the product and categories for the current hour.
For categories I'm creating links like this

```
'href'  => $this->url->link('product/happy_hours', 'id='   . $category['category_id'])
```

In the `.tpl` file the link looks like this:

```
index.php?route=product/happy_hours&id=65
```

In the database table `oc_url_alias` I've added a record for the SEO link for 'happy_hours' like

```
query = product/happy_hours
keyword = happyhours
```

Now I can access now domain.com/happyhours

But how do i create SEO link like this for categories?

```
domain.com/happyhours/categoryname
```

**Update**

fix posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some how manage to do it

in soe_url.php controller

```
elseif ($key == 'id') {

                $categories[] = $value;

                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = 'happy_hour_id=" . (int)$category . "'");

                    if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
                        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
                    } else {
                        $url = '';

                        break;
                    }
                }
                    unset($data[$key]);
            }
```

in database url_alias

```
query = happy_hour_id=65
keyword = happyhour/category name
```

in final

```
domain.com/happyhour/category name
```